# validation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation

Im doing validation for the forms. I have input for question text, and 4 input forms for 4 answers with radio buttons and number input for points.

If I validate this forms, user have to create 4 answers to the DB, but what if user would store only 3? How validate in this way? Now it show error that the fields are required if Im trying to store 3 answers.

My validation

```
    public function store(Test $test, Request $request)
        {
           $this->validate($request, [
                'text' => 'required',
                'point' => 'required',
                'correct' => 'required'

            ]);

        $question = new Question();

        if($request->has('picture')) {
        $question->picture = $request->file('picture')->get();
    }
        $question->text = $request->input('text');
        $question->test_id = $test->id;
        $question->save();

        foreach ($request->input('answer') as $_index => $_answer)
        {
            if ( $_answer['text'] ) {
                $answer = new Answer();
                $answer->text = $_answer['text'];
                $answer->point = $_answer['point'];

                $answer->correct = ($request->input('correctanswer') == $_index) ? 1 : 0;

                $answer->question_id = $question->id;

                $answer->save();

            }
    }
```

Blade

```
  {!! Form::open(['route' =>
                      ['question.store', $test->id],
                       'class' => 'form',
                       'method' => 'post',
                       'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'

                                 ]
                               ) !!}


                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('text', 'Question text') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('text', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'required' => 'required'] ) !!}
                            </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('picture', 'picture') !!}
                            {!! Form::file('picture', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                          </div>
                            <?php

                            for($answers_counter = 0; $answers_counter < 4; $answers_counter++) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">Answer{{ $answers_counter + 1 }}</span>
                                    <div class="input-group-text">
                                        <input type="radio" name="correctanswer" id="answer[{{ $answers_counter }}]" value="{{ $answers_counter }}" placeholder="Answer{{ $answers_counter + 1 }}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                {!! Form::text('answer[' . $answers_counter . '][text]', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Points</span>
                                    </div>
                                    {!! Form::number('answer[' . $answers_counter . '][point]', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>
```

Can somedy help me please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you turn off the strictMode then sql should accept empty input, but that's just workaround.. When you paste this on the top of your `Model`:

```
protected static $strictMode = false;
```